# MODULE_NOT_FOUND issue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I stuck at MODULE_NOT_FOUND , I have checked other questions related to it and tried their soultions but could not get succeed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I am trying to create node.js with mysql db using TypeORM and trying to import User entity created in entity folder where I have file name User.ts

[image]

This is my folder structure.

Below is package.json

```
{
  "name": "mysql-typeorm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

Below is my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const { User } = require('./entity/User')

const { DataSource , createConnection} =  require('typeorm')
const app = express()

const port = 3000 || process.env.port

app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})

const appDataSource = new DataSource({
    type:"mysql",
    host:"localhost",
    port:3308,
    username:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"booksDB",
    synchronize:true,
    logging:true,
    entities:[User]
});

appDataSource.initialize().then((res)=> {
    console.log(`db is connected`)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`${err}`)
})

app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    res.send({
        test:'Testing is done'
    })
})
```

Below is my User.ts for entity User located in entity folder.

```
import {Entity , PrimaryGeneratedColumn , Column , BaseEntity } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

 @Column()
    name!: string;

 @Column()
    email!: string;

 @Column()
    phone!: string;

}
```

I am getting error like this

```
Error: Cannot find module './entity/User'
Require stack:
- D:\2023\elluminous\technical_growth_program\node.js\node-mysql-typeorm\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\2023\elluminous\technical_growth_program\node.js\node-mysql-typeorm\app.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\2023\\elluminous\\technical_growth_program\\node.js\\node-mysql-typeorm\\app.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Also I have tried with

```
import { User } from "./entity/User"
```

in app.js but I am getting error like this

```
(node:15732) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
D:\2023\elluminous\technical_growth_program\node.js\node-mysql-typeorm\app.js:3
import { User } from "./entity/User"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Try `import { User } from "./entity/User"` instead of `require`.

Comment: @perak Sola  , I have already used like what you have suggested. but still getting error.I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix JS and TS. In your scripts you are using `nodemon app.js` which means that you are starting a regular NodeJS process and it will be restarted should `app.js` or any imported dependencies change.

TS cannot be executed by NodeJS and should be first transformed into JS using `tsc` compiler. For dev mode you would want to have it served and for that you would use `ts-node` which I can see in your deps but is unused in the scripts.

To tell `nodemon` that you want to use TS you should change `app.js` to `app.ts` so it's using TS instead of JS. This should fix the issue.